proposition 6.22 in Awodey's category theory textbook
Proposition 6.22 reads:
For every CCC (Cartesian closed category) $C$, there is a poset $I$ and a functor, $$y: C \to \textrm{Sets}^I,$$ that is injective on both objects and arrows and preserves CCC structure. Moreover, every map between objects in the image of $y$ is itself in the image of $y$ ($y$ is "full").
Then Awodey continues: "The full proof of this result involves methods from topos theory that are beyond the scope of this book. But a significant part of it, to be given below, is entirely analygous to the proof of the poset case, and will again be a consequence of the Yoneda lemma."
I think I understand the second half (the significant part) that the embedding $y$ is indeed the Yoneda embedding (the co-completion process). But the textbook is not providing any reference to the full proposition, with the CCC structure and poset part. So I am asking if anyone has any good reference to this proposition in topos theory (context in typed lambda calculus models is a plus).

You know any topos theory? It is a big weird subject and can take some time to get used to, so i would be careful diving into it. (preliminaries in my head should be alg. Topology and alg geometry,in particular sheaf theory)
